# Is the app developer the same as the app owner?

Tags: google-play, app-store

If I ask the app development company to host an app on their App store or their Google play store accounts, does this make them the legal owners of the app?

I want to stay the legal owner of the app. Does this affect my ownership rights by any means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure ownership of the App concept, IP and confidentiality:-
- Sign a IP rights document with the Dev Company.
- Sign a NDA with the Dev Company.

You might need more documents depending upon the laws of your country, so this step is not possible without consulting a lawyer.

Also, you need to ensure that:-
- You get all the source code with proper documentation.
- Also, make sure there are no encrypted files/libraries present in the source code.

Since, 2013 Apps can also be transferred between accounts if you happen to create one later.

================================

**On the flip side**

Why do you want to get into such a mess?

It is easy and cheap to create a Developer account. Just some straighforward paperwork and not more that 100$ for each platform (compared to the amount of resources you have already invested in creating  the App)

Once you have the account, give the Dev company *Developer access* to your account. They can upload the App to your account with it. Once this is done and you have also ensured the you have all the source code, you have no dependencies on the Dev company.